# How to 'likes' a post on Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an android application integrating Facebook for post on Facebook wall.Now i want **to like my post** programatically.My searching results shows that **OBJECT ID** or **COMMENT ID** is needed for this purpose.How to obtain this?I am using Facebook Graph Api.I know that  it is not possible to **'like'** pages via the Graph API.
    My code for post to wall is

```
    facebook.dialog(activity, "feed", bundle, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                logoutFacebook();
            }
        });
```

I there any way to like a post?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the `publish_stream` permission and you have the `POST_ID` that you want to create the like for, then its simply doing the following:

```
mAsyncRunner.request("/POST_ID/likes", null, "POST", new likeListener(), null);
```

The `likeListener` can then determine whether it succeeded or not.  Facebook returns in the response true if successful, false if not.  [Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

If you don't have the `POST_ID` then you have to get it somehow.  You should be more specific as to what type of post you want to like.  For example, if you just created a post on someone's wall using our SDK, we return the post ID in your `onComplete` method in your code above in the bundle `values` if it succeeds.  Save that post id and use it as the `POST_ID` in the example I gave you earlier.

Comment: Thank you.Is it possible to like a page of facebook programatically or how to handle facebook 'Likes' button except using webview?

Comment: Currently, there's no way to like a Page on Facebook programmatically.  The best way would be to redirect the user to your Facebook page in a `WebView` or in the browser for them to like (to prevent spamming, obviously).

Comment: I implemented facebook Likes button using Webview.But when trying to like some pages it shows Error in red color and no other details.Why this happen?How to solve this?

Comment: You should ask a new question for this problem.  Make sure to show your code and any relevant stack traces or logcat messages in your question.  Ping me so I can help you in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force users to like your application(due to spamming reasons). The only way you can get them to like your page/app is embedding the like fbml code or iframe in a web view. That documentation is in place to like a friends wall post or comment or photo, as those are the types of items you can like for a user, in case for example you were writing a Facebook client. If that is what you are trying to do, don't send the app_id as you are doing, but send the post id of the users post.